# Set permission for all files in a folder in C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform

Is there a cross-platform way to recursively set permissions for the contents of a folder in C++?

I don't want to rely on system calls.

Comment: [Qt](https://www.qt.io) has classes that can help you with that.

Comment: Not *all* platforms support folders, especially those in the Embedded Systems area.

Answer (score 3):

Example to grant 0777 to all files and folders in a directory using C++17 and its [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem):

- [`std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) to iterate
  through the directory
- [`std::filesystem::permissions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/permissions) to set the permissions for each file
- [`std::filesystem::perms`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/perms) to decide, which permissions should be set

Code:

```
#include <exception>
//#include <filesystem>
#include <experimental/filesystem> // Use this for most compilers as of yet.

//namespace fs = std::filesystem;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; // Use this for most compilers as of yet.

int main()
{
    fs::path directory = "change/permission/of/descendants";
    for (auto& path : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(directory))
    {
        try {
            fs::permissions(path, fs::perms::all); // Uses fs::perm_options::replace.
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
            // Handle exception or use another overload of fs::permissions() 
            // with std::error_code.
        }           
    }
}
```

---

If e.g. `fs::perm_options::add` instead of `fs::perm_options::replace` is desired, then this is not yet cross-platform. `experimental/filesystem` of VS17 doesn't know [`fs::perm_options`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/perm_options) and includes `add` and `remove` as `fs::perms::add_perms` and `fs::perms::remove_perms` instead. This implies that the signature of `std::filesystem::permissions` is slightly different:

Std:

```
fs::permissions(path, fs::perms::all, fs::perm_options::add);
```

VS17:

```
fs::permissions(path, fs::perms::add_perms | fs::perms::all); // VS17.
```

Comment: Have you considered boost:filesystem?

Comment: Since you mention this Visual Studio incompatibility is this meant to be the answer or are you looking for other answers and this material should have been in the question??

Comment: @drescherjm I've chosen this as answer since it is working as long as `perm_options` is not set manually. However it is true that b/c of the second part this might also fit into the question. Sorry, I didn't see that when creating the question.